# Apache CXF with Spring Boot - problems with routes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

I'm integrating Apache CXF with a Spring Boot application - but I cannot get my controllers to be automatically loaded. I'm using a Java based configuration (no XML).

Here's what I tried:

- Explicitily add the resoruces package to `@ComponentScan`

  => got a `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` on every controller
- Resources package not in `@ComponentScan` paths

  => the controllers are completly ignored (no entry from the `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` debug logs)

I'm declaring each controller this way:

```
@Component
@RequestMapping("/me")
public class MeResource {
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Object getLoggedUser() {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return principal;
    }
}
```

What am I missing to get the controllers picked up automatically?

Comment: Spring Boot is *opinionated* from the get-go, so it might have something to do with other dependencies that you've included in your classpath (either direct or transitive) such as Jersey. If it's a maven project it may be helpful to share the pom. Either way, setting the root log level to debug should help in figuring out what Spring is doing behind the curtain. Any particular reason you're not going with what [Spring is already offering](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to run a `mvn clean` - and add the Controller packages in the `@ComponentScan`. Duplication Bean Exceptions disappeared.